# Trouble shooting Java Modbus code

Tags: java, spring, modbus

I'm currently following this guide: http://jamod.sourceforge.net/kb/serial_master_howto.html

To try and achieve modbus communication to a serial device. I'm using the Spring Tool Suite. Please note I am an amateur programmer.

Code:

```
   package Test1;

 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import net.wimpi.modbus.*;
 import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.*;
 import net.wimpi.modbus.io.*;
 import net.wimpi.modbus.net.*;
 import net.wimpi.modbus.util.*;

  public class JaMod {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try { /* The important instances of the classes mentioned before */
        SerialConnection con = null; //the connection
    ModbusSerialTransaction trans = null; //the transaction
    ReadInputRegistersRequest req = null; //the request
    ReadInputRegistersResponse res = null; //the response

    /* Variables for storing the parameters */
    String portname= "seven"; //the name of the serial port to be used
    int unitid = 9; //the unit identifier we will be talking to
    int ref = 1000; //the reference, where to start reading from
    int count = 5; //the count of IR's to read
    int repeat = 5; //a loop for repeating the transaction


    //2. Set master identifier
    //ModbusCoupler.createModbusCoupler(null);
    ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(1);      

    //3. Setup serial parameters
    SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();
    params.setPortName(portname);
    params.setBaudRate(19200);
    params.setDatabits(8);
    params.setParity("None");
    params.setStopbits(1);
    params.setEncoding("ascii");
    params.setEcho(false);

    //4. Open the connection
    con = new SerialConnection(params);
    con.open();

    //5. Prepare a request
    req = new ReadInputRegistersRequest(ref, count);
    req.setUnitID(unitid);
    req.setHeadless();

    //6. Prepare a transaction
    trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);
    trans.setRequest(req);

    //7. Execute the transaction repeat times
    int k = 0;
    do {
      trans.execute();
      res = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
      for (int n = 0; n < res.getWordCount(); n++) {
        System.out.println("Word " + n + "=" + res.getRegisterValue(n));
      }
      k++;
    } while (k < repeat);

    //8. Close the connection
    con.close();  

} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
}//main

  }//class SerialAITest
```

[Imported Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyTbe.png)

Despite it being seemingly straight forward, I am getting this warning:
- Import Java.net
and
- Import java.io

Are never used. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. Nothing is wrong. To get rid of the warning, remove the import statements for `java.net.*` and `java.io*` because you're not using them. Add them back when you need to use a class from these packages. (Usually, your IDE has a command like "organize imports" that will add/remove imports until you only have the ones that you need)

Comment: I gave that a shot and got this result:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.comm.SunrayInfo.isSessionActive()Z
 at com.sun.comm.SunrayInfo.isSessionActive(Native Method)
 at com.sun.comm.Portmapping.registerCommPorts(Portmapping.java:155)
 at com.sun.comm.Portmapping.refreshPortDatabase(Portmapping.java:100)
 at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:138)
 at net.wimpi.modbus.net.SerialConnection.open(SerialConnection.java:87)
 at Test1.JaMod.main(JaMod.java:44)

Apologies for the mess, can't seem to format my text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909385/what-does-unsatisfiedlinkerror-mean/28909498#28909498

Comment: New problem: No rxtxSerial in java.library.path while loading driver gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver......Now while I do follow, the following: Find your jar in Project -> properties -> Java build path. Click on the + to open the JAR's properties, select Native library location and edit it to point to RXTX's shared library (.DLL, .so, .dylib).......it does not allow me to select a .dll or .so file..they're all greyed out. (I'm using Ubuntu)